# Use current user and domainname in Property

Tags: wix

I'm creating a windows installer with the WiX toolset. I would like to make an URL reservation with the [UrlReservation Element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/http/urlreservation.html) for that I would like to get the current user and domainname.

This is what I did:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
 xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
 xmlns:firext="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension"
 xmlns:httpext="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/HttpExtension">


<Product Id="*" ... >

    <Property Id ="PROP_URL_RESERVATION_DOMAIN_NAME" Value="$(env.USERDOMAIN)" Secure="yes" />
    <Property Id ="PROP_URL_RESERVATION_USER_NAME" Value="$(env.USERNAME)" Secure="yes" />
    
    <UI>
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree_MyApp" />
    </UI>
    
</Product>
```

The userdomain and username are set correctly but they are compiled in (during candlelight) and are then constant. But I would like to init with the current user and domain when the installer is started.

Can you help me that PROP_URL_RESERVATION_DOMAIN_NAME and PROP_URL_RESERVATION_USER_NAME are initialised with the current when the installer is started?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go the way with RegistrySearch:

```
    <Property Id ="PROP_URL_RESERVATION_DOMAIN_NAME" Value="DOMAIN" Secure="yes">
        <RegistrySearch Id="DomainRegistrySearch"
                        Root="HKCU"
                        Key="Volatile Environment"
                        Name="USERDOMAIN"
                        Type="raw" /> 
    </Property>
    <Property Id ="PROP_URL_RESERVATION_USER_NAME" Value="USER" Secure="yes">
        <RegistrySearch Id="UserRegistrySearch"
                        Root="HKCU"
                        Key="Volatile Environment"
                        Name="USERNAME"
                        Type="raw" />
    </Property>
```